# Probability and search Tree

Tags: probability, trees

I need some help with the following question.

Given the random permutations of $ n > 2 $  numbers.
Now, creating a binary search tree and puting it the organs one by one.

Denote the input organs by $ a1< ... <an $ .

a.  $ \forall \:\: 1 \leq i \neq j  \leq n $ calculate the probability that $ ai $ is the **predecessor** of the $ aj $ in the generated tree.

b. $ \forall \:\: 1 \leq i   \leq n $
calculate the **mean depth** of the $ ai $ in tree generated  tree.

And in addition, calculate the **mean of the successors number** of the $ ai $ in tree generated  tree.

Thanks in advance